# No module named 'googleapiclient.disocvery' for YouTube api

Tags: google-api-discovery

I am trying to use YouTube API. I need to install google api python client and using the correct command. I am trying to pip install from my terminal and here is the command I am using-

```html
pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

It runs the code successfully and shows that the Requirement Already Satisfied. Yet when I get back to jupyter notebook, it keep throwing the error.

Code I run-

```html
from googleapiclient.disocvery import build
import pandas as pd
```

Error I am getting-

```html
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2792/1819596350.py in <module>
----> 1 from googleapiclient.disocvery import build
      2 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient.disocvery'
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I checked previous threads here, and the advice was to use pip3 in place of pip when run the command on terminal which I did without any success.

Here is the last part of the code from terminal to show that requirement is satisfied. The message is very long, I am posting the last part of it-

```html
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\qazws\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=1.19.0->google-api-python-client) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\qazws\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0dev,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client) (2.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\qazws\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0dev,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\qazws\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0dev,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client) (1.26.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\qazws\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0->google-api-core!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0dev,>=1.31.5->google-api-python-client) (2021.10.8)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\qazws\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you misstyped `googleapiclient.disocvery`, the correct spelling is `googleapiclient.discovery`.